# How can I use getTotalLength and getPointAtLength on a scaled path?

Tags: javascript, svg

getTotalLength and getPointAtLength seem to ignore transforms. On this:

```
<path id="path"
      transform="scale(1 1)"
      d="M 137.077 222.345 C 124.162 222.345 120.887 258.264 120.887 265.519 C 120.887 289.603 115.13 315.169 129.522 325.962 C 148.995 340.568 167.219 344.292 180.251 347.549 C 210.399 355.086 228.43 359.24 246.091 360.502 C 281.021 362.997 302.891 362.903 322.724 361.581 C 357.33 359.274 374.138 351.966 391.803 347.549 C 409.773 343.057 427.54 326.205 432.818 313.01 C 441.201 292.051 458.843 282.426 464.119 266.598"
      stroke="black" fill="none" />
```

this code

```
var p = document.getElementById('path')
var l = p.getTotalLength()
console.log(l)
```

prints 493.8976745605469

and on this:

```
<path id="path"
      transform="scale(2 2)"
      d="M 137.077 222.345 C 124.162 222.345 120.887 258.264 120.887 265.519 C 120.887 289.603 115.13 315.169 129.522 325.962 C 148.995 340.568 167.219 344.292 180.251 347.549 C 210.399 355.086 228.43 359.24 246.091 360.502 C 281.021 362.997 302.891 362.903 322.724 361.581 C 357.33 359.274 374.138 351.966 391.803 347.549 C 409.773 343.057 427.54 326.205 432.818 313.01 C 441.201 292.051 458.843 282.426 464.119 266.598"
      stroke="black" fill="none" />
```

exactly the same value.

How can I get getTotalLength and getPointAtLength to calculate according to the transforms?

Comment: Why would that be useful?

Comment: @RobertLongson - I want to position a series of shapes along the transformed path

Comment: move the transform to a parent element and then do everything in that space or alternatively transform all the shapes the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `.getTotalLength()` the math is easy enough. If you have a uniform scale, the length can simply be multiplied with that number; or more generally for

```
transform = scale(sx, sy) =>
length' = length * √(sx² + sy²)
```

But then, if you would try to find a point along the path, you must use the *untransformed* values. If the result of `.getTotalLength()` is 400 and the path is uniformly scaled with 2, the total length might be 800, but to find the point 90% along the path, you still need to compute `.getPointAtLength(360)`.

To transform a point you found with `.getPointAtLength()`, you can use a [`SVGMatrix`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#InterfaceSVGMatrix) like this:

```
var p = document.getElementById('path');
var svg = p.ownerSVGElement; // only <svg> elements have a method to init SVGMatrix

var matrix = svg.createSVGMatrix().scaleNonUniform(sx, sy); // or .scale(s) for uniform scale

var point = p.getPointAtLength(length).matrixTransform(matrix);
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to get total length for non-uniform shape ?